# Setting ${xxx} in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsp-tags

I have several parameters/variables in my Spring jsp.

I need to clear them out before the next jsp/controller is called.

I am going to clear them out at the bottom of the .jsp
Is there a catch all that will do this?
What is the best way to handle this?

Should I use the c:set  tag?  Will that work for all ${xx}  possibilities?
ie.

```
<c:set name="xxx" value="new value"/>
```

where xxx is a bean property, or a standalone variable, or whatever I can access via ${xxx}  in my jsp.

Comment: What? Why are you doing this in JSP? What is the nature of these variables that they need to be "cleared" at all?!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<c:remove var=”userStatus” scope=”request” />`

The var attribute must be a String literal. It can’t be an expression.
If you leave out the scope then the attribute is removed from ALL scopes.